# How to redirect a request to a PHP file "internally"?

Tags: php

I'm introducing a RegEx based URI router to a legacy PHP codebase and some requests still need to be handled the old way (by loading a `.php` file) before the transition can be completed.

The router is working fine and I can build the `.php` file path for the requests that will be handled this way. How can I, given the PHP file path, delegate the request entirely to this file?

I thought a simple `require $filepath;` would do but I'm getting include errors from that script when it tries to include other files.

I tried some ideas without success:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $sControllerPath;
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.dirname($sControllerPath));
require $sControllerPath;
```

Comment: You may have to change directory to the `dirname($sControllerPath);` if it uses relative includes.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston this should be answer because it solved my problem.

Comment: I posted it an an answer @philix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change directory to the `dirname($sControllerPath);` if it uses relative includes.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $sControllerPath;
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.dirname($sControllerPath));
// for relative includes like ./file.php
chdir(dirname($sControllerPath));
require $sControllerPath;
```

Comment: Using chdir(). Thanks! Sometimes I forget the scripty nature of PHP.

Comment: That is the probably the single most important gotcha about php for new devs or people new to the language. Once you understand its origins, the madness makes sense.

Comment: I don't consider myself new to the language but I've been consistenly using autoloaders and `include __DIR__.'/file.php'` for years and never had to deal with this include madness before.

Comment: That wasn't directed at you, it was just a general comment about how **fun** php is.